# Oracle backup and recovery

Tags: oracle

During recovery Oracle writes the following error:

```
RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown log: thread 1 seq 9 lowscn 4034762
```

I have used in mount mode this command:

```
change archivelog all crosscheck;
delete expired archivelog all;
```

Then restore and tried to recover again:But still `RMAN-06054` error.Than I wrote:

```
run{
SET UNTIL SEQUENCE 9 THREAD 1;
RESTORE DATABASE;
RECOVER DATABASE;
}
```

It helped me to recover database...But after that when I do the backup and then recover the same error occurs and solution is the same... I wonder to solve this problem without  `SET UNTIL SEQUENCE 9 THREAD 1;`
maybe I should unregister this archive log from control file(I am using control file not catalog) Can you tell me how?

Comment: How did you backup (and restore) the database? Which command did you use? Which operation did you perform at O/S level (copy files, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "unregister" a backupset (or a part of it) from the control file, juste delete the files and use the "crosscheck" command at RMAN prompt:

```
rman> host rm -rf /what/ever/db/backup/*.arch
rman> crosscheck archivelog all;
```

Have a look at the backup and recovery books in Oracle Documentation Library: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/portal.portal_db?selected=3#index-BAC (this is for 10Gr2)

Answer (score 1):

this is normal from 10g and up - the control file is requesting what it assumes to be the next archive log seq. Once the restore completes, and the recover applies at least one archivelog, I wouldn't worry about it. I would just type:

sql 'alter database open resetlogs';